# jquery ajaxStart function and ajaxComplete function wont work in ie7 and ie8

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi stackoverflow jquery experts,

I've got a problem on my ajaxStart function and ajaxComplete function, it wont work on ie7 and ie8, but works perfectly in ie9. below is my code. Hope you can helf me on this. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#findAcademy').bind('keyup', function() { 
    $(".loader").ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: "findBook.php?action=populateacademy&query="+this.value+"",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("#viewAcademy").append('<div class="nameWrapper"><input name="checkMeT" type="checkbox" value="'+item.bookId+'|::|'+item.bookName+'"/><span title="'+item.bookName+'" class="checkBoxSpan">'+item.bookName+'</span></div>');
        });
    }});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ,

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('.loader').show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
  $('.loader').hide();
});
```

try this way

```
$('.loader').show();
 $.ajax({
      url: "findBook.php?action=populateacademy&query="+this.value+"",
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
            $('.loader').hide();
        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
            $("#viewAcademy").append('<div class="nameWrapper"><input name="checkMeT" type="checkbox" value="'+item.bookId+'|::|'+item.bookName+'"/><span title="'+item.bookName+'" class="checkBoxSpan">'+item.bookName+'</span></div>');
        });
    }});
```

Comment: @siri: thanks for your quick reply, ive tried your example, it shows the loader but wont hide.

Comment: @andsien , let me take a look at it,

Comment: @siri: ive updated my code with its parent function, sorry but i dont have a live page for it right know. I only test it on my local host.

Comment: andsien , if this is creating problem like this you can probably do it otherway , show the busy loader before ajax starts and in the success of ajax hide that ,it will be simple that way ,

Comment: @andsien,thats great to hear.